a custom systemctl service isn't working | working but only one-time
so I made this .service in /etc/systemd/system  to run a script when a Thumb Drive is mounted, here is the code:
#!/bin/bash

[Unit]
Description=My Flash Backup script trigger
After=media-Drive.mount

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/user/Documents/Backup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

The problem is that it gives a failed (Result: protocol)
this means that I need to restart the daemon every time I want to mount the thumb drive, which just makes manually launching it from a terminal alias much easier... how to make it so that I don't need to reload?
Also, when I try to systemctl start Backup.service it gives
Job for Backup.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status Backup.service" and "journalctl -xeu Backup.service" for details.

and with systemctl status Backup.service
Aug 11 20:38:22 creator-5 systemd[1]: Backup.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Aug 11 20:38:22 creator-5 systemd[1]: Failed to start Backup.service - My Flash Backup script trigger.

What did I understand or done wrong?
edit1: if it matters, the script is executable, and it's a rsync command
Edit2: now it works fine, now I must make it so that it works every time the drive is mounted and not only the first time in each login session.
The service now looks like this:
[Unit]
Description=My Flash Backup script trigger
After=media-Drive.mount

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/user/Documents/Backup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Edit3: also, if possible, i'd like to make it run every 10 mins the drive is mounted...

Why are putting #!/bin/bash in the beginning of your .service file?

How did you decide to use the notify type for your service? Are you sure that's appropriate? Does your Backup.sh script actually report its status back to systemd?

Does your script depend on your environment ($PATH, etc) that' you need to tell the .service file about.

@FedKad because it's shebang?

@steeldriver i didn't know that :), no, the script just does it's thing and then poofs into non-existance

@waltinator it depends on a path in home/Documents and then the drive

Hmm... so maybe try type=oneshot? And as @FedKad said you don't need the shebang (although I think systemd will ignore it) - unit files are not scripts

@steeldriver done that, now it's working without errors, now i need to make it so that it runs every time the drive is mounted and not only the first time in a session

@steeldriver I just copied it from a similar former post with someone wanting to mount a drive at a custom location and do a backup.
this is the link
